# App Script: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

Things that i have:

1. Google sheet with rows of sales data
2. Google Doc (template file)

I setup an app script to create PDF document for each sales within the google sheet based on the template file. What it does:

1. make a copy of the template file (google doc)
2. replace the value in the template file with data from the google sheet
3. generate a PDF version of the file and save it in the correct google drive folder
   ~ loop through all rows of data

It have been years since we first set it up and been functioning all the while. However for new user, when we shared the file to them, they always encounter this error:

"No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it."

Normally it is resolved after we ask them to setup an google account under the same work email we are using. (ps: we are using non google email account)

Can someone help?

I know that normally for new users, there is a permission setting popup to authorize the app script access when they are using it for the first time.

1. However this pop up does not work for all user (which i wonder why>?)
2. For those user that does not have the popup.. they will received the mentioned error. How to go about fixing it?
3. What is actually causing the permission access pop to NOT popup>?

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between `Normally it is resolved after we ask them to setup an google account under the same work email we are using.` and your current issue? And, from `(ps: we are using non google email account)`, I guessed that in your situation, your accounts might be in Google Workspace. If my understanding is correct, how about asking the reason for your current issue with the administrator of Google Workspace? But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: we are using work email, i.e: name@abc_company.com - however, we realise for our appscript to work, they need to be login as a google account. Thus, we created a google account with the same work email (name@abc_company.com) for all our employees. And that seems to does the trick. But however, sometime even after creating a google account, the appscript is still not working.

Comment: To explain simply - if i share it to a google account user (nix.yap@gmail.com) the appscript within file is functioning properly. But if i share it to the non google account user (i.e: name@abc_company.com) - the appscript failed to function. Thus, that is the reason for us to create a google account for new user. However, as mention doesnt resolve the issue all the time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful.